# How to access all vertexes within the same patch in Tessellation Control Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, tessellation

I want to do LOD in Tessenllation Control Shader. And my method is to calculate the area each patch occupyed on screen coordinate, and set different tessellation level for them.

So I need to access all vertices within a patch and I do so like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    position_screen[i] = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
}
```

where i defined my patch in TCS like:

```
#version 400  
layout( vertices=4 ) out;
```

and here is related codes in OpenGL:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, rect_index_buffer);
glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 4);
glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, RECT_INDEX_SIZE, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

However the result is strange.The tessellation level is related to the area on the scrren, but all patches have the same tessellation level.

So what's the problem?

I guess it's the way I try getting access to vertices within a patch went wrong. Then how can I do that?

The following is codes in my Tessellation Control Shader, I hope it helps:

```
#version 400  
layout( vertices=4 ) out; 

uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;

uniform float window_height;
uniform float window_width;

float PI = 3.14159;

float calcTriangleArea(float l[3])  //Heron's formula
{
    float p = (l[0] + l[1] + l[2]) / 2.0;

    return sqrt(p * (p - l[0]) * (p - l[1]) * (p - l[2]));
}

float calcSqureArea(vec4 position[4])
{
    vec2 position_screen[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        position_screen[i] = position[i].xy;
    }

    float l[4];

    for(int i = 0;i < 4;i++)
    {
        l[i] = length(position_screen[(i + 1) % 4] - position_screen[i % 4]);
    }

    float diagonal = length(position_screen[2] - position_screen[0]);

    float l1[3];
    float l2[3];

    l1[0] = l[0];
    l1[1] = l[1];
    l1[2] = diagonal;

    l2[0] = l[2];
    l2[1] = l[3];
    l2[2] = diagonal;

    float area = calcTriangleArea(l1) + calcTriangleArea(l2);

    return area;
}

float checkInsideView(vec4 position[4]) //check if the patch is visible
{
    int flag = 4;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if((position[i].x >= -window_width / 2.0) && (position[i].x <= window_width / 2.0) && 
    (position[i].y >= -window_height / 2.0) && (position[i].y <= window_height / 2.0))
        {
            flag --;
        }
    }

    if(flag == 0)   //all 4 vertices are visible
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else if(flag == 4)  //not all visible
    {
        return 2.0;
    }
    else    //all vertices are not visible
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
}

float calcLODLevel()
{
    vec4 position_screen[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        position_screen[i] = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
    }

    float in_view_level = checkInsideView(position_screen);

    //tess number is decided by the area that this patch covers on 
    //the screen
    float area = calcSqureArea(position_screen);
    float level = sqrt(area);   

    if(in_view_level == 1.0)    
    {
        level /= sqrt(2);
    }
    //dont do tessellation
    //if this patch is not visible
    else if(in_view_level == 2.0)
    {
        level = 1.0;
    }

    return level;
}

void main()
{
    gl_out[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position = gl_in[gl_InvocationID].gl_Position;

    float lod_level = calcLODLevel();

    gl_TessLevelOuter[0] = lod_level;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[1] = lod_level;
    gl_TessLevelOuter[2] = lod_level;  
    gl_TessLevelOuter[3] = lod_level;  
    gl_TessLevelInner[0] = lod_level;
    gl_TessLevelInner[1] = lod_level;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your calculation of the screen coordinates, resulting in the tessellation levels to be too small. The key part is this:

```
position_screen[i] = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
```

What you're calculating here are clip coordinates, not screen coordinates. To get screen coordinates from clip coordinates, you need to:

- Perform the perspective division. This gives you NDC (Normalized Device Coordinates) in the range [-1.0, 1.0].
- Calculate screen coordinates from the NDC.

In code, the calculation could look like this:

```
vec4 posClip = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * gl_in[i].gl_Position;
vec2 posNdc = posClip.xy * (1.0 / posClip.w);
vec2 posScreen = 0.5 * (posNdc + 1.0) * vec2(window_width, window_height);
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, but this tess level is not too small indeed. What I want to figure out most is why all patches share the same tess level while they are supposed to have different tess levels.

Comment: With the calculation you're using, the result will only depend on the size in world coordinate space. If you want to use the size in screen space, you need the perspective division.